# preloader как на тостере

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать preloadbar как на toster.ru?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь плагином `NProgress`

http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/

Пример использования в `Ajax` запросах на `jQuery`. Завязываемся на событиях.

```
// отправка запроса, запускаем прогрессбар
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
  return NProgress.set(0.6).start();
});
// запрос отправлен, останавливаем прогрессбар
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  return NProgress.done();
});
// запрос вернул ошибку, останавливаем прогрессбар
$(document).ajaxError(function() {
  return NProgress.done();
});
```

Comment: Подключил плагин, а как сделать так, что бы прогресс бар исчезал после загрузки страницы?

Comment: `$( window ).load(function() { NProgress.done(); });`